# How to send the string

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-wifi

I'm currently working on a project using WifiP2pService and connecting each device on Wifi. I'm not quite sure how to make the devices connect with each other, so they can play the same song together.

Currently I have the chat fragment set up so they can communicate with each other, and the devices connect.  Now I want to make it where if you are the group owner, the string of mediaID gets sent to the client and they are able to get the mediaID and play the same song.

So here's my musicPlayerActivity class.

```
package com.example.android.uamp.ui;

import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.android.uamp.R;
import com.example.android.uamp.utils.LogHelper;

/**
 * Main activity for the music player.
 * This class hold the MediaBrowser and the MediaController instances. It      will create a MediaBrowser
 * when it is created and connect/disconnect on start/stop. Thus, a MediaBrowser will be always
 * connected while this activity is running.
 */
public class MusicPlayerActivity extends BaseActivity
    implements MediaBrowserFragment.MediaFragmentListener {

private static final String TAG = LogHelper.makeLogTag(MusicPlayerActivity.class);
private static final String SAVED_MEDIA_ID="com.example.android.uamp.MEDIA_ID";
private static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "uamp_list_container";

public static final String EXTRA_START_FULLSCREEN =
        "com.example.android.uamp.EXTRA_START_FULLSCREEN";

/**
 * Optionally used with {@link #EXTRA_START_FULLSCREEN} to carry a MediaDescription to
 * the {@link FullScreenPlayerActivity}, speeding up the screen rendering
 * while the {@link android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat} is connecting.
 */
public static final String EXTRA_CURRENT_MEDIA_DESCRIPTION =
    "com.example.android.uamp.CURRENT_MEDIA_DESCRIPTION";

private Bundle mVoiceSearchParams;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LogHelper.d(TAG, "Activity onCreate");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    initializeToolbar();
    initializeFromParams(savedInstanceState, getIntent());

    // Only check if a full screen player is needed on the first time:
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        startFullScreenActivityIfNeeded(getIntent());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    String mediaId = getMediaId();
    if (mediaId != null) {
        outState.putString(SAVED_MEDIA_ID, mediaId);
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onMediaItemSelected(MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem item) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onMediaItemSelected, mediaId=" + item.getMediaId());
    if (item.isPlayable()) {
        getSupportMediaController().getTransportControls()
                .playFromMediaId(item.getMediaId(), null);
    } else if (item.isBrowsable()) {
        navigateToBrowser(item.getMediaId());
    } else {
        LogHelper.w(TAG, "Ignoring MediaItem that is neither browsable nor playable: ",
                "mediaId=", item.getMediaId());
    }
}

@Override
public void setToolbarTitle(CharSequence title) {
    LogHelper.d(TAG, "Setting toolbar title to ", title);
    if (title == null) {
        title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    }
    setTitle(title);
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    LogHelper.d(TAG, "onNewIntent, intent=" + intent);
    initializeFromParams(null, intent);
    startFullScreenActivityIfNeeded(intent);
}

private void startFullScreenActivityIfNeeded(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null && intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_START_FULLSCREEN, false)) {
        Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(this, FullScreenPlayerActivity.class)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
            .putExtra(EXTRA_CURRENT_MEDIA_DESCRIPTION,
                intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_CURRENT_MEDIA_DESCRIPTION));
        startActivity(fullScreenIntent);
    }
}

protected void initializeFromParams(Bundle savedInstanceState, Intent intent) {
    String mediaId = null;
    // check if we were started from a "Play XYZ" voice search. If so, we save the extras
    // (which contain the query details) in a parameter, so we can reuse it later, when the
    // MediaSession is connected.
    if (intent.getAction() != null
        && intent.getAction().equals(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH)) {
        mVoiceSearchParams = intent.getExtras();
        LogHelper.d(TAG, "Starting from voice search query=",
            mVoiceSearchParams.getString(SearchManager.QUERY));
    } else {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // If there is a saved media ID, use it
            mediaId = savedInstanceState.getString(SAVED_MEDIA_ID);
        }
    }
    navigateToBrowser(mediaId);
}

private void navigateToBrowser(String mediaId) {
    LogHelper.d(TAG, "navigateToBrowser, mediaId=" + mediaId);
    MediaBrowserFragment fragment = getBrowseFragment();

    if (fragment == null || !TextUtils.equals(fragment.getMediaId(), mediaId)) {
        fragment = new MediaBrowserFragment();
        fragment.setMediaId(mediaId);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(
            R.animator.slide_in_from_right, R.animator.slide_out_to_left,
            R.animator.slide_in_from_left, R.animator.slide_out_to_right);
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG);
        // If this is not the top level media (root), we add it to the fragment back stack,
        // so that actionbar toggle and Back will work appropriately:
        if (mediaId != null) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

public String getMediaId() {
    MediaBrowserFragment fragment = getBrowseFragment();
    if (fragment == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return fragment.getMediaId();
}

private MediaBrowserFragment getBrowseFragment() {
    return (MediaBrowserFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onMediaControllerConnected() {
    if (mVoiceSearchParams != null) {
        // If there is a bootstrap parameter to start from a search query, we
        // send it to the media session and set it to null, so it won't play again
        // when the activity is stopped/started or recreated:
        String query = mVoiceSearchParams.getString(SearchManager.QUERY);
        getSupportMediaController().getTransportControls()
                .playFromSearch(query, mVoiceSearchParams);
        mVoiceSearchParams = null;
    }
    getBrowseFragment().onConnected();
}
}
```

And here's my Chat Manager class

```
package com.example.android.uamp.PhoneSync;


import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
/**
 * Handles reading and writing of messages with socket buffers. Uses a Handler
 * to post messages to UI thread for UI updates.
 */
public class ChatManager implements Runnable {
private Socket socket = null;
private Handler handler;
public ChatManager(Socket socket, Handler handler) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.handler = handler;
}
private InputStream iStream;
private OutputStream oStream;
private static final String TAG = "ChatHandler";
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        iStream = socket.getInputStream();
        oStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;
        handler.obtainMessage(PhoneSync.MY_HANDLE, this)
                .sendToTarget();
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = iStream.read(buffer);
                if (bytes == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                Log.d(TAG, "Rec:" + String.valueOf(buffer));
                handler.obtainMessage(PhoneSync.MESSAGE_READ,
                        bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public void write(byte[] buffer) {
    try {
        oStream.write(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
    }
}
}
```

My client socket handler

```
package com.example.android.uamp.PhoneSync;


import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
public class ClientSocketHandler extends Thread {
private static final String TAG = "ClientSocketHandler";
private Handler handler;
private ChatManager chat;
private InetAddress mAddress;
public ClientSocketHandler(Handler handler, InetAddress groupOwnerAddress) {
    this.handler = handler;
    this.mAddress = groupOwnerAddress;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    try {
        socket.bind(null);
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(mAddress.getHostAddress(),
                PhoneSync.SERVER_PORT), 5000);
        Log.d(TAG, "Launching the I/O handler");
        chat = new ChatManager(socket, handler);
        new Thread(chat).start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }
}
public ChatManager getChat() {
    return chat;
}
}
```

My Group Owner Socket Handler

```
package com.example.android.uamp.PhoneSync;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
/**
 * The implementation of a ServerSocket handler. This is used by the wifi p2p
 * group owner.
 */
public class GroupOwnerSocketHandler extends Thread {
ServerSocket socket = null;
private final int THREAD_COUNT = 10;
private Handler handler;
private static final String TAG = "GroupOwnerSocketHandler";
public GroupOwnerSocketHandler(Handler handler) throws IOException {
    try {
        socket = new ServerSocket(4545);
        this.handler = handler;
        Log.d("GroupOwnerSocketHandler", "Socket Started");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        pool.shutdownNow();
        throw e;
    }
}
/**
 * A ThreadPool for client sockets.
 */
private final ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
        THREAD_COUNT, THREAD_COUNT, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            // A blocking operation. Initiate a ChatManager instance when
            // there is a new connection
            pool.execute(new ChatManager(socket.accept(), handler));
            Log.d(TAG, "Launching the I/O handler");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                if (socket != null && !socket.isClosed())
                    socket.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            pool.shutdownNow();
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

my WifiChatFragment class

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.example.android.uamp.R;
/**
 * This fragment handles chat related UI which includes a list view for messages
 * and a message entry field with send button.
 */
public class WiFiChatFragment extends Fragment {
private View view;
private ChatManager chatManager;
private TextView chatLine;
private ListView listView;
ChatMessageAdapter adapter = null;
private List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
    chatLine = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtChatLine);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    adapter = new ChatMessageAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.id.text1,
            items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    view.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (chatManager != null) {
                        chatManager.write(chatLine.getText().toString()
                                .getBytes());
                        pushMessage("Me: " + chatLine.getText().toString());
                        chatLine.setText("");
                        chatLine.clearFocus();
                    }
                }
            });
    return view;
}
public interface MessageTarget {
    public Handler getHandler();
}
public void setChatManager(ChatManager obj) {
    chatManager = obj;
}
public void pushMessage(String readMessage) {
    adapter.add(readMessage);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
/**
 * ArrayAdapter to manage chat messages.
 */
public class ChatMessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    List<String> messages = null;
    public ChatMessageAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                              List<String> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
        }
        String message = items.get(position);
        if (message != null && !message.isEmpty()) {
            TextView nameText = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            if (nameText != null) {
                nameText.setText(message);
                if (message.startsWith("Me: ")) {
                    nameText.setTextAppearance(getActivity(),
                            R.style.TextAppearance_AppCompat_Large);
                } else {
                    nameText.setTextAppearance(getActivity(),
                            R.style.TextAppearance_AppCompat_Headline);
                }
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}
}
```

And last, this is the part of PhoneSync class where it takes what was given from the Chat Manager and Chat Fragment.

```
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_READ:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
            String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
            Log.d(TAG, readMessage);
            (chatFragment).pushMessage("Buddy: " + readMessage);
            break;
        case MY_HANDLE:
            Object obj = msg.obj;
            (chatFragment).setChatManager((ChatManager) obj);
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    receiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(manager, channel, this);
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
@Override
public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo p2pInfo) {
    Thread handler = null;
    /*
     * The group owner accepts connections using a server socket and then spawns a
     * client socket for every client. This is handled by {@code
     * GroupOwnerSocketHandler}
     */
    if (p2pInfo.isGroupOwner) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connected as group owner");
        try {
            handler = new GroupOwnerSocketHandler(
                    ((MessageTarget) this).getHandler());
            handler.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "Failed to create a server thread - " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connected as peer");
        handler = new ClientSocketHandler(
                ((MessageTarget) this).getHandler(),
                p2pInfo.groupOwnerAddress);
        handler.start();
    }
    chatFragment = new WiFiChatFragment();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container_root, chatFragment).commit();
    statusTxtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
public void appendStatus(String status) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    statusTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text);
    String current = statusTxtView.getText().toString();
    statusTxtView.setText(current + "\n" + status);
}
}
```